# Measure to Calculate difference between values in existing column row by row

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is my table

[image]

My table name is VARIANCE_19_20

BELOW IS MEASURE I AM TRYING, BUT DIDN'T WORK.

```
VARIANCE = 
VAR NextIndex = VARIANCE_19_20[INDEX] - 1
RETURN
    VARIANCE_19_20[TC Count]
        - CALCULATE (
            VALUES ( VARIANCE_19_20[TC Count] ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( VARIANCE_19_20), VARIANCE_19_20[INDEX] = NextIndex)
        )
```

I am trying to write a measure to see difference in Variance column as shown in above table.

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to build a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: Hi Rado, thanks for the response. I am trying to create measure so my below formulae work to create up and down arrows.     Key= if((VARIANCE_19_20[variance]>0,UNICHAR ( 128315 ), UNICHAR ( 9650 ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution; create a calculated column using the following logic:

```
Delta =
VAR ShiftedIdx = VARIANCE_19_20[Index] - 1
VAR CurrentValue = VARIANCE_19_20[TC Count]
RETURN
    IF (
        VARIANCE_19_20[Index] = 1,
        0,
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( VARIANCE_19_20[TC Count] ),
            FILTER ( VARIANCE_19_20, VARIANCE_19_20[Index] = ShiftedIdx )
        ) - CurrentValue
    )
```

Which will produce the following results:

[image]

Comment: Hi Stelio, thanks you very much for the code. It worked perfectly and other thing what i am trying is to insert another column with up and down arrows and below code not picking up calculated column values, it work for only measured values.                                                             KEY = IF
(VARIANCE_19_20[DELTA]>0,UNICHAR ( 128315 ), UNICHAR ( 9650 ))

Comment: hey no problem, happy to help. Have you ensured the calculated column is the correct data type? Also, I believe the UNICHAR function is only available on certain versions of SSAS.

Comment: Hi Stelio, apologies for delay. The data is just excel table in one drive.